# Ajax DOM javascript loop an array into another one

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

In my javascript code i have an array like thisone:

[image]

i would to loop into first note and loop inside into 'mtitoli' inner array for extract its 'ttipo' and 'tdescr' values
i try this code:

```
$.each(value, function(index, value) {  
    $.each(value['meds'][index].mtitoli, function(titind, titval) {
        console.log("Titoli " + titval);
    })
})
```

but i get just [Object object] as response.

How can i extract values from array inside my array??

So many thanks in advance

Comment: use this for log `console.log("Titoli ", titval);`

Comment: please include the sample array in a snippet so that we can give you back functional code.

Comment: Please do not post image of console, but provide a sample of your array in JavaScript literal notation (text format, as [{ "mname": "GIUSEPPE", ... }, { ..... }]). Your code references a `meds` property which is nowhere in the screenshot. So please provide sample code and values so we can run the script and see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log can take arbitrary number of arguments so you can put all data you need to log separating it by commas or concat same type values

```
 console.log("Titoli " , titval);

 console.log("Titoli " + JSON.stringify(titval));
```

```js
titval=[{"id":1}]

console.log("Titoli " + titval);
console.log("Titoli " , titval);
console.log("Titoli " , JSON.stringify(titval));
```